# Notification.Builder class is not working as it is deprecated

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, deprecated

as i have started working with notifications in android,i found that **Notification.Builder** class is deprecated and my code is giving run time error ,is there any way to solve this problem or to create notifications without using Notification.Builder class.

thank you in advance :)

Comment: You need to read on the documentation since the methods may have changed from previous years.